# Admob is not working in LIBGDX project

Tags: java, android, firebase, libgdx, admob

I connected my project with firebase ads, and I am not able to use AdView, MobileAds etc classes. It showing can not resolve symbol (Suggestion: Add library 'play-services-ads-lite:11.2.0' to classpath). I connected firebase direct from android studio.
Here's my both gradles.

**build.gradle (project)**

```
 buildscript {


repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'


    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

  }
}

allprojects {
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "idea"

version = '1.0'
ext {
    appName = "Drunken Bird"
    gdxVersion = '1.9.6'
    roboVMVersion = '2.3.1'
    box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
    ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
    aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    admobVersion='8.3.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"          }
   }
  }

  project(":android") {
apply plugin: "android"

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"


}
 }

   project(":core") {
apply plugin: "java"


dependencies {
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"

}
}

 tasks.eclipse.doLast {
delete ".project"
   }
```

**build.gradle (app)**

```
     android {
            buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
            compileSdkVersion 26
            sourceSets {
                main {
                    manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                    java.srcDirs = ['src']
                    aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                    renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                    res.srcDirs = ['res']
                    assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
                    jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
                }

                instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
            }
            packagingOptions {
                exclude 'META-INF/robovm/ios/robovm.xml'
            }
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.aman.drunkenbird"
                minSdkVersion 14
                targetSdkVersion 26
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
            productFlavors {
            }
        }
        // called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
        // the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
        // so they get packed with the APK.
        task copyAndroidNatives() {
            file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
            file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
            file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
            file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
            file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

            configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
                def outputDir = null
                if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
                if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
                if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
                if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
                if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
                if (outputDir != null) {
                    copy {
                        from zipTree(jar)
                        into outputDir
                        include "*.so"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task run(type: Exec) {
            def path
            def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
            if (localProperties.exists()) {
                Properties properties = new Properties()
                localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
                    properties.load(instr)
                }
                def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
                if (sdkDir) {
                    path = sdkDir
                } else {
                    path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
                }
            } else {
                path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
            }

            def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
            commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.aman.drunkenbird/com.aman.drunkenbird.AndroidLauncher'
        }
        // sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
        eclipse {
            // need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
            // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
            sourceSets {
                main {
                    java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
                }
            }

            jdt {
                sourceCompatibility = 1.6
                targetCompatibility = 1.6
            }

            classpath {
                plusConfigurations += [project.configurations.compile]
                containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'
            }

            project {
                name = appName + "-android"
                natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
                buildCommands.clear();
                buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
                buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
                buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
                buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
            }
        }
        // sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
        idea {
            module {
                sourceDirs += file("src");
                scopes = [COMPILE: [plus: [project.configurations.compile]]]

                iml {
                    withXml {
                        def node = it.asNode()
                        def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                        builder.current = node;
                        builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                            facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                                configuration {
                                    option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value: "true")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        dependencies {

            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.2.0'

            implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.2.0'

        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        }
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the your question says, add this to you build.gradle (app)

```
implementation 'play-services-ads-lite:11.2.0'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: try using compile for your dependencies instead of implementation

Answer (score 0):

Add Google's Maven repository in root `build.gradle` file, that's for all module

```
repositories {

     mavenLocal()
     mavenCentral()
     maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
     maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
     maven {  url "https://maven.google.com" }   //<-- Google's Maven repository
}
```

After that inject Ads dependency in android module

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.2.0'
}
```

Refresh your project.

Comment: what is the version of Google Repository inside `SDK Tools` tab of Android SDK ?

Comment: Google Repository version is 57

Comment: Make sure you've disabled Offline work of `Global Gradle settings`

Comment: Yes, it is disabled

Comment: remove `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads` because you're using firebase ads API